# Manifest Merger failed with multiple errors, suggest solution does not work

Tags: android, android-manifest

There are already many items on this topic and i have read a lot of them but without any succes.

In my Merged Menifest the following error

```
Merging Errors: 
Warning Package name 'android.support.graphics.drawable' used in: AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml. 
animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 manifest 
Warning Package name 'androidx.versionedparcelable' used in: AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml. 
support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0 manifest 
Error: Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from 
AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 is also present at AndroidManifest.xml:24:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory). 
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:20:5-83:19 to override. 
TripMemory.app main manifest (this file), line 21
```

Now the warning annoy me but lets leave them for now.
The error is the problem and i have no clue what the problem is.
It suggests to add a "tools:replace..." but when i do that i just get the next error and besides it feels like bypassing the issue and not solving it.

I also don't understand why i am getting error's I did not update studio and i was just fixing some layout things. not even error's just improvements.
It then first started with AndriodX messages. and then this. Maybe that's a clue for somebody.

my AndroidManifest.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.nocompany.tripmemory">

    <!-- location via GPS -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- needed to get photo's of the phone -->
    <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />-->

    <!-- needed to use the camera and export -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- needed to use the camera -->
    <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />-->

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Default">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Default.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                ....
```

Can anybody help me how to read this error and find the solution?

**Update**
as suggested by ommonsWare i added by build.gradle (app) file here
*put it as an image so the colors are clear.*
[image: Build.grade (app) part 1]
[image: Build.gradle (app) part 2]

Comment: Your app's `build.gradle` file is using some *very* old dependencies, ones that have not been updated in several years. Those are the source of your difficulty. You might want to consider editing your question to include your `dependencies` closure of your `app` module's `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update should anybody face the same.
In the end i have choosen to rebuild my app from scratch.
I luckely is a small app and that was a lot faster because i went from error to error to error.
In retrospect this problem also allowed me to restructure some things in the groundworks making the app beter.